# How to create a circular animation when a tab is pressed in (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller

Essentially I would like to recreate the following animation that occurs in the Youtube app when a tab is selected.

[image]

This is currently what I have in my custom Tab Bar Controller class:

```
import UIKit

class AnimatedTabBarController: UITabBarController {

    private var bounceAnimation: CAKeyframeAnimation = {
        let bounceAnimation = CAKeyframeAnimation(keyPath: "transform.scale")
        bounceAnimation.values = [1.0, 0.9, 1.00, 1.00, 1.0]
        bounceAnimation.duration = TimeInterval(0.3)
        bounceAnimation.calculationMode = CAAnimationCalculationMode.cubic
        return bounceAnimation
    }()

    override func tabBar(_ tabBar: UITabBar, didSelect item: UITabBarItem) {
        // find index if the selected tab bar item, then find the corresponding view and get its image, the view position is offset by 1 because the first item is the background (at least in this case)
        guard let idx = tabBar.items?.index(of: item), tabBar.subviews.count > idx + 1, let imageView = tabBar.subviews[idx + 1].subviews.first as? UIImageView else {
            return
        }

        imageView.layer.add(bounceAnimation, forKey: nil)
    }
}
```

The code above allows my tabs to bounce inwards when being selected, what can be added to the class to also add the circle and have it subtly disappear.

Answer (score 0):

There are several methods you can use. You can take third party or you can create custom. In my case, I use custom.

1. take a viewController in storyboard
2. create same view as your question's images
3. set containerView in same viewController
4. give touchupinside animation in buttons or use coreGraphichs or use layers
5. add controller in containerView when tap.

Comment: There is no way to do this in a custom class?

Comment: I find that difficult to believe

Comment: so man you have to learn core graphics to give custom effects otherwise this is the only one solution I think..!